# Select from Multiple Entrys in MYSQL one Word

Tags: mysql

how can i make a select in this [Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5POO.png) to get all Entrys includes "Yannick".

```
SELECT * 
  FROM todo 
 WHERE forUser like Yannick
```

and

```
SELECT * 
  FROM todo 
 WHERE forUser like 'Yannick'
```

do not work.

Couldn't find any way.

Thanks

Comment: Yannic should be wrapped in quotes, it’s a string. Also, like is used to search a value inside a string. So like ‘%Yannic%’ means contains the string Yannic. For an exact match use = and not like

Comment: Please don’t _abuse_ this site as a place to get the absolute basics taught, that is not what it is for. This is something _you_ should be reading up on in a beginner tutorial or the documentation, on your own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use operator `%word%` so:

```
SELECT * FROM todo WHERE forUser like '%Yannick%'
```

How reference ( [Mysql Official reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)):

- `%` matches any number of characters, even zero characters.
- `_` matches exactly one character.

Another suggest if 'Yannick' is a user input please learn how to prepare stmt for prevent sql inject

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use
SELECT * FROM todo
WHERE  foruser ='yannick';